# Replace Amazon s3 with S3ForMe

Tags: django, amazon-s3, bucket

I have added to my Django application the storage of static and multimedia files in bucket Amazon S3. I need to change to another option because of problems with my account. I want to take advantage of S3ForMe.

In order to configure everything efficiently, I changed the keys, and I have to change API endpoint (which looks like this):

```
<Error>
  <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
  <Message>Access Denied</Message>
  <RequestId>15554191115cb5cfe7adb60</RequestId>
  <HostId>storage0-3.s3for.me</HostId>
</Error>
```

I have no idea where to make this change in my Django application or on PythonAnywhere. Where to change these APIs. When adding Amazon S3, I never added something like that.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming when you are using `django-storages`, you need to define `AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL` when you are not using Amazon S3. You need to put it in `settings.py` like this:

```
AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL = 'https://storage0-3.s3for.me'
```

Now, if you want to serve the static contents in different path(lets say you are using cloudfront/varnish to serve the contents in a different path), then you need to add this line as well:

```
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = 'cdn.mydomain.com'
```

More information can be found [here](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/1.5.2/backends/amazon-S3.html).